# return a function inside a function

Tags: javascript, angular

[source code](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#defining-custom-validators) is here. The part I'm having trouble with is this:

```js
export function forbiddenNameValidator(nameRe: RegExp): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
    const forbidden = nameRe.test(control.value);
    return forbidden ? {forbiddenName: {value: control.value}} : null;
  };
}
```

The part I don't understand is the return part. We're returning a function within a function, and it confused me a lot. I've looked around a bit but haven't been able to find any references to this topic. can you help me?

Comment: Well, a function can return anything. It can return `undefined`, or a number, a string... or even another function. But then you have to call this new function :  `const returnedFunction = forbiddenNameValidator("foo"); const finalResult = returnedFunction("bar");` or in short : `const finalResult = forbiddenNameValidator("foo")("bar")`

Comment: but here we always send one argument: 
https://stackblitz.com/run?file=src%2Fapp%2Fshared%2Fforbidden-name.directive.ts

Comment: The link redirects to the home page

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9bo4pq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fshared%2Fforbidden-name.directive.ts

Comment: @furkiakça `forbiddenNameValidator(new RegExp(this.forbiddenName, 'i'))(control)` is most definitely passing two arguments in a curried fashion. To simplify it's: `forbiddenNameValidator(one)(two)`

Comment: wow i got it, thank you